# Java 8 stream combiner never called

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm writing a custom java 8 collector which is supposed to compute the average of a POJO which has a `getValue()` method. Here's the code:

```
public static Collector<BoltAggregationData, BigDecimal[], BigDecimal> avgCollector = new Collector<BoltAggregationData, BigDecimal[], BigDecimal>() {

        @Override
        public Supplier<BigDecimal[]> supplier() {
            return () -> {
                BigDecimal[] start = new BigDecimal[2];
                start[0] = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                start[1] = BigDecimal.ZERO;
                return start;
            };
        }

        @Override
        public BiConsumer<BigDecimal[], BoltAggregationData> accumulator() {
            return (a,b) ->  {
                a[0] = a[0].add(b.getValue());
                a[1] = a[1].add(BigDecimal.ONE);
            };
        }

        @Override
        public BinaryOperator<BigDecimal[]> combiner() {
            return (a,b) -> {
                a[0] = a[0].add(b[0]);
                a[1] = a[1].add(b[1]);
                return a;
            };
        }

        @Override
        public Function<BigDecimal[], BigDecimal> finisher() {
            return (a) -> {
                return a[0].divide(a[1], 6 , RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            };
        }

        private final Set<Characteristics> CHARACTERISTICS = new HashSet<Characteristics>(Arrays.asList(Characteristics.CONCURRENT, Characteristics.UNORDERED));

        @Override
        public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
            return CHARACTERISTICS;
        }

    };
```

It all works well in the non-parallel case. However, when I use a `parallelStream()`, it sometimes doesn't work. For example, given the values from 1 to 10, it computes( 53/9 instead of 55/10). When debugging the debugger never hits the breakpoint in the combiner() function. Is there some kind of flag that I need to set?

Comment: I did upvote both, thanks for your answer too :) I just found the other answer somehow clearer. Thanks for the tip on the EnumSet too.

Comment: That’s ok, I just noticed that you accepted (or tried to accept) both in a short time interval, so I just wanted to clear potential confusion.

Comment: Note there are much better ways to do this, for example a [cumulative moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average).

Comment: As a side note, you could still size down your code by using [```Collector.of```](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-), if you're using an anonymous class any ways...

Comment: If we are at additional ways to improve the code, there are array initializers: `BigDecimal[] start =  { BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO }; return start;` or `() -> new BigDecimal[] { BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal.ZERO }` using the `… -> expression` form, which is also applicable to the finisher: `a -> a[0].divide(a[1], 6 , RoundingMode.HALF_UP)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the `CONCURRENT` characteristic, which does something else than you would think it might:

> Indicates that this collector is *concurrent*, meaning that
>     the result container can support the accumulator function being
>     called concurrently with the same result container from multiple
>     threads.

*Instead* of calling the combiner, the accumulator is being called concurrently, using the same `BigDecimal[] a` for all threads. The access to `a` is not atomic, so it goes wrong:

```
Thread1 -> retrieves value of a[0]: 3
Thread2 -> retrieves value of a[0]: 3
Thread1 -> adds own value: 3 + 3 = 6
Thread2 -> adds own value: 3 + 4 = 7
Thread1 -> writes 6 to a[0]
Thread2 -> writes 7 to a[0]
```

Making the value of `a[0]` 7 when it should be 10. The same kind of thing can happen with `a[1]`, so results can be inconsistent.

---

If you remove the `CONCURRENT` characteristic, the combiner will get used instead.

Comment: Would it do to use an `AtomicInteger` (or `AtomicLong`) instead of a `BigInteger` instead? Could the `CONCURRENT` characteristic be used then?

Comment: @dcsohl During testing I found that surrounding the to lines in the accumulator with ```synchronized(this){...}``` also solved the problem. But my intuition says that the use of this characteristic should not be forced, but rather used if the result container supports concurrent operations any ways.

Comment: @dcsohl: of course, making the accumulator function thread safe can solve the problem, as that’s what the `CONCURRENT` characteristic implies, that this function is thread safe. However, it also suggests a performance benefit of concurrent evaluation over local accumulation plus merging, which is not the case here (it’s rarely the case).

Answer (score 19):

Well, that’s exactly what you request when specifying [`Characteristics.CONCURRENT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html#CONCURRENT):

> Indicates that this collector is *concurrent*, meaning that the result container can support the accumulator function being called concurrently with the same result container from multiple threads.

If that’s not the case, as with your `Collector`, you shouldn’t specify that flag.

---

As a side note, `new HashSet<Characteristics>(Arrays.asList(Characteristics.CONCURRENT, Characteristics.UNORDERED));` is quite inefficient for specifying characteristics. You can just use `EnumSet.of(Characteristics.CONCURRENT, Characteristics.UNORDERED)`. When you remove the wrong *concurrent* characteristic, you may use either `EnumSet.of(Characteristics.UNORDERED)` or `Collections.singleton(Characteristics.UNORDERED)`, but a `HashSet` definitely is overkill.